# Developer Dashboard is not appearing in my sharepoint 2010 enterprise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Developer Dashboard is not appearing in my sharepoint 2010 enterprise.
How can i get it over the page?

Comment: What do you mean not appearing, nothing shows when you click the link? you have activated it right? Are you using custom master page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can ebable using powershell or stsadm.

PowerShell

```
$svc=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$ddsetting=$svc.DeveloperDashboardSettings
$ddsetting.DisplayLevel=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDeveloperDashboardLevel]::OnDemand
$ddsetting.Update()
```

http://sharepointadam.com/2009/10/20/how-to-enable-the-developer-dashboard/

Comment: Exactly. Thank you Mr. Chandegar. Now i can see Developer Dashboard and it works as i expect it. Thanks again..